# Keep enabled checkboxes at top of jQuery DataTables, despite sort order

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables, isenabled

I want my jQuery DataTable to always display the group of enabled checkbox rows at the top and the disabled checkbox rows underneath. So far I can only achieve this by clicking on the first header label 'clicks'.  Essentially I add the class 'greyed out' to the relevant rows and sort on it.  Problem is that I can't sustain those 2 groups when I sort on the other headers.  I also need the order to be kept when I use the column filters.  For example, clicking on 'Longs' in the 'Product Group' dropdown filter should show the 2 enabled 'Longs' rows at the top and the 1 disabled 'Longs' row at the bottom.  I'm afraid I'm confused and frankly out of my depth on next steps.  Any advice much appreciated. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mxb6vp3b/

```html
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.0/css/select.dataTables.min.css"></script>


<form id="frm-example" action="/nosuchpage" method="POST">
  <table id="example" class="display select" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Clicks</th>
        <th>Trading Code</th>
        <th>Product Group</th>
        <th>Product description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr id="row250200">
        <td><input id="HS250200" type="checkbox" value="HS 250200" /></td>
        <td> 250200 </td>
        <td> Longs </td>
        <td> Iron Ore - unroasted </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="row260111">
        <td><input id="HS260111" type="checkbox" value="HS 260111" /></td>
        <td> 260111 </td>
        <td> Raw Materials - Iron ore </td>
        <td> Iron Ore - fines, concentrate, lump </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="row730490" class="TypeCarbon_Alloy">
        <td><input id="HS730490" type="checkbox" value="HS 730490" /></td>
        <td> 730490 </td>
        <td> Pipe &amp; tube - Seamless </td>
        <td> Seamless tube - other </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="row730512" class="TypeCarbon_Alloy">
        <td><input id="HS730512" type="checkbox" value="HS 730512" /></td>
        <td> 730512 </td>
        <td> Longs </td>
        <td> Welded tube - line pipe, LW, >406.4mm </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="row730230" class="TypeCarbon_Alloy_Stainless">
        <td><input id="HS730230" type="checkbox" value="HS 730230" /></td>
        <td> 730230 </td>
        <td> Longs </td>
        <td> Railway Materials </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="row721921" class="TypeStainless">
        <td><input id="HS721921" type="checkbox" value="HS 721921" /></td>
        <td> 721921 </td>
        <td> Flats - HR plate </td>
        <td> HR plate - discrete or CTL, >10mm </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

```css
.grey_out {
  color: lightgrey;
}
```

```js
$(function() {

    // Disable all rows
    $('#example td input').prop("disabled", true).closest('tr').addClass('grey_out');
    // Eanable relevant rows
    $("#HS260111, #HS730512, #HS730230").prop("disabled", false).closest('tr').removeClass('grey_out');


    $('#example').DataTable({
        orderCellsTop: true,
        scrollY: '50vh',
        scrollCollapse: true,
        orderCellsTop: true,

        'columnDefs': [{
            'targets': 0,
            'orderDataType': 'dom-checkbox',
            'orderable': true,
        }],

        "order": [
            [0, "asc"]
        ],
        responsive: true,

        initComplete: function() {
            this.api().columns([1, 2, 3]).every(function() {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value="">Show all</option></select>')

                    .appendTo($(column.header()))
                    .on('change', function() {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                            .draw();
                    });

                column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
                    select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                });

            });
        }
    });


    // Sort for Enabled'
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-checkbox'] = function(settings, col) {
        return this.api().column(col, {
            order: 'index'
        }).nodes().map(function(td, i) {
            return $(td).parent().is(':not(.grey_out)') ? '0' : '1';
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [**`orderFixed`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/orderFixed).

> [...] the ordering specified by this option will always be applied to
>   the table, regardless of user interaction.

Now add a hidden column to your table and use that as base for `orderFixed`:

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   columnDefs: [
     { targets: 0, visible: false }
   ],
   orderFixed: [0, 'desc']
})
```

Then update the hidden column with for example `1` and `0` when its sibling checkbox is checked or unchecked :

```js
$('#example').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
   var row = table.row($(this).closest('tr'));
   table.cell({ row: row.index(), column: 0 } ).data( this.checked ? 1 : 0 )
   row.invalidate().draw()
})
```

"checked" rows will now always stay on top regardless of how the user sort the table.

I took the markup above and made a new demo for simplicity -> **http://jsfiddle.net/6e56cu8u/**

Comment: Apologies @davidkonrad for my lateness.  Perhaps I'm not quite understanding you but I asked about always keeping enabled checkboxes above disabled ones.  Now, WITHIN this fixed pattern, all sorting needs to work as usual, eg clicking 'clicks' should make any checked checkboxes rise to top, or bottom of the enabled group, ie they must always stay above the disabled checkboxes.  To test, I added from my fiddle my 2 lines of jQuery that dealt with disabling/enabling checkboxes, to the start of your code.  But when I run your code the enabled checkboxes don't split from the disabled checkboxes.

Comment: Hey @Silverburch, The solution for you is exactly the same, there is no difference. You can just handle disabled checkboxes as `-1` for example. I have fixed your fiddle so it works this way -> **https://jsfiddle.net/mxb6vp3b/16/** Disabled checkboxes on the bottom, sorting within enabled checkboxes on the top.

Comment: @Silverburch Generally I am reluctant to use a fiddle like yours as base since no one can learn from it. Though the problem is generic and the question is good, you have some very narrow specialised code (like hardcoded id's, disabling checkboxes by code and then enabling some of them again etc) that no one else is likely to do or would have in their own setup.  If I took your code and added a solution people would only get confused, thats why I stick to a more simplistic generic model :)

Comment: Ah, learning a lot here.  I'm now starting to see how you're applying orderFixed and it's really impressive.  The only thing that remains is that your revised fiddle automatically throws checked checkbox rows to the top of the table as soon as the tick is put in.  I'd simply like that to happen ONLY when the user clicks on the 'Clicks' header to sort the rows (asc/desc).  In other words I'd like 'Clicks sort' to act just like the 'header sort' in the other columns. I thought I'd be able to do this myself but 2 hours later I still can't. Still a lot to learn!

Comment: I do understand your issues about updating my fiddle.  In future I'll try to take specialised code out.  But hopefully in this instance, seeing how your solution is applied can still help others to some extent.

Comment: @Silverburch "*I'd simply like that to happen ONLY when the user clicks on the 'Clicks' header..*"  You could skip the checkbox click handler and instead update all the hidden columns (1/0) in a loop when the user click on the "Clicks header".

Comment: Suddenly obvious when you know how!  Much appreciate all your help on this @davidkonrad.